# How to use cross validation to estimate autocorrelation?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

I have a stationary time series and I want to calculate the autocorrelation coefficient of order 1. For that I use OLS. I know the autocorrelation parameters change over the time. Thus it is not trivial to fix a window length for the regression. Moreover I can easily do over-fitting by finding the windows which optimize a criterion such as mean squared error, for example.

Can I use cross validation to find the optimal window length?

Comment: How is it possible for a time series to be both "stationary" and to have a changing autocorrelation?

Comment: Sorry, the autoccorelation is assumed to move in ]-1;1[;

Comment: So, just to be clear: you have a *nonstationary* time series for which you wish to estimate a *moving* autocorrelation coefficient.  For that, you use a *moving window* OLS procedure.  Your question concerns finding an "optimal" window length.  Right?  Also, what do you wish to optimize?  Make the bias small?  Minimize estimation variance?  Create reliable predictions?  Estimate a parameter in a model for the change of autocorrelation?

Comment: thanks for your answers.Your right. I want to minimize estimation variance. Since i use moving windows, my AR(1) parameter move over the time. I want to know if there exist a procedure to choose the windows length wich minimize the estimation variance whithout overfiting i.e choose the best windows in sample.